# Validate database data in .NET project

Tags: vb.net

Im searching for 85 in a database table column. Column values may include as below
" 85" or " 85" or "852" or 385" or 13857 or "85/1" etc....

```vb
"SELECT * FROM FullData where (SYNO LIKE '%" + Z1 + "%' OR SYNO LIKE '%" + Z2 + "%'")
```

This is my code.
Can anyone help me out to get only 85 or parts or 85 that is ( 85/1  85/A etc...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. This looks like a SQL question, not a VB.net question. 2. Please use Parameterized queries. 3. Apart from the last two characters at the end of that string being the wrong way round - should be )" not ") - how is that query not working? Assuming the values of Z1 or Z2 come out to 85 that looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend this is an Sql Server database. Your code might look like this.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dt = GetFullData("85")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetFullData(SearchString As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql = "Select * FROM FullData where SYNO Like @SearchString;"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchString", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"%{SearchString}%"
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Submitting my issue more clearly
SNO   
231 229   
123   
12 3    
1 2 3   
121 122 123/P  
1234 1231  

IF SEARCHED FOR 123 in SNO RESULT SHOULD BE (123)  (123/P)
   But current results are (123) (1234, 1231) 
SAME WITH PLNO

My code is
 
Dim MainSearch As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + FullPath2 + "'")
MainSearch.Open()

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM FullData where (SYNO LIKE ‘%”+ trim(txtSno.text) +”%’, MainSearch)

Dim SPer As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader